# What should be the SQL query in MySQL for the given Tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

We have three tables-

a) ACTORS: This table contains  contains the following fields: unique id (id), first name (fname), last name (Iname).

b) MOVIES: This table contains the following fields: unique id (id), movie name (fname), release year (year).

c) MOVIE CAST: This table relates ACTORS with MOVIES and contains the following fields:actor id (actor_id), movie id (movie_id)

We have to find ACTOR_ID, MOVIE NAME for all actors who only acted in movies before 1975,final result will have two columns "ACTOR_ID", "MOVIE NAME",sort final result by name in alphabetical order.

Comment: Are you familiar with joins, WHERE clauses etc? Show us what you have tried first.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What is your question?

Comment: Actually I have tried for joins but not able to get perfect output for three tables

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
SELECT t1.id, t3.fname
FROM actors t1
JOIN ‘movie_cast’ t2 ON t2.id=t1.id
JOIN movies t3 ON t3.id=t2.movie_id
WHERE t3.year<1976
ORDER BY t1.fname
```

Unless you need to remove all actors playing also after 1975.

Comment: Hi, I have the above command for same query by not able to get output.Can you explain t1,t2,t3 and id column is same for both actors and movies table?